# VSCode - how to add more keybindings to the integrated terminal

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I have managed to add a few keybindings to the integrated terminal of VSCode, but want to add more. How can I add my own keybindings?

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    { "key": "cmd+right",                "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
                                            "when": "terminalFocus" },
    { "key": "cmd+left",                "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious",
                                            "when": "terminalFocus" },
    { "key": "cmd+delete",                "command": "workbench.action.terminal.deleteAllRight",
                                            "when": "terminalFocus" }
]
```

The first two work, but the last one does not, and I'm guessing this is due to the fact that the integrated terminal does not have this option. Is there a way to add it? I want to have all my regular terminal keybindings here as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
{ 
        "key": "cmd+x",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.kill",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

You probably know this one already, but just in case. It only kills the current terminal but you could press it a few times for the same functionality.